# Error while deploying mule appliction in RTF runtime 3.9.1

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-platform, anypoint-rtf

I am currently creating ci/cd for RTF deployments. Now I managed to make it for Mule runtim 4.x only for runtime 3.9.1 things are a little different. For example, another mule maven version is used, namely; 2.3.2 this does not work via connectedAPP but only with the old method username and password. However, during deployment I get the connection time out error.

I found an article from mulesoft which indicates that there is probably network/infrastructure issue but this can't be right, because mule runtime 4.x works just fine.

My pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.mulesoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-test-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>hello-test-project</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <mule.version>3.9.1-20220127</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.7</mule.tools.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <runtimeFabricDeployment>
                        <uri>https://eu1.anypoint.mulesoft.com</uri>
                        <muleVersion>3.9.1</muleVersion>
                        <username>xxxxxx</username>
                        <password>xxxxxx</password>
                        <applicationName>hello-test-project</applicationName>
                        <environment>DEV</environment>
                        <target>RTF</target>
                        <provider>MC</provider>
                        <deploymentSettings>
                            <memoryReserved>100Mi</memoryReserved>
                        </deploymentSettings>
                    </runtimeFabricDeployment>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mule-public</id>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:2.3.2:deploy (deploy) on project hello-test-project-391: Execution deploy of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:2.3.2:deploy failed: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:2.3.2:deploy (deploy) on project hello-test-project-391: Execution deploy of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:2.3.2:deploy failed: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution deploy of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:2.3.2:deploy failed: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply (HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke (ClientRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call (JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call (JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope (RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke (JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method (JerseyInvocation.java:437)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post (JerseyInvocation.java:343)
    at org.mule.tools.client.core.AbstractClient.post (AbstractClient.java:55)
    at org.mule.tools.client.authentication.AuthenticationServiceClient.login (AuthenticationServiceClient.java:111)
    at org.mule.tools.client.authentication.AuthenticationServiceClient.getBearerToken (AuthenticationServiceClient.java:71)
    at org.mule.tools.client.AbstractMuleClient.getBearerToken (AbstractMuleClient.java:303)
    at org.mule.tools.client.AbstractMuleClient.init (AbstractMuleClient.java:79)
    at org.mule.tools.client.core.AbstractClient.initialize (AbstractClient.java:104)
    at org.mule.tools.client.fabric.RuntimeFabricClient.getAgentsPath (RuntimeFabricClient.java:113)
    at org.mule.tools.client.fabric.RuntimeFabricClient.getTargets (RuntimeFabricClient.java:118)
    at org.mule.tools.deployment.fabric.RequestBuilder.resolveTargetId (RequestBuilder.java:121)
    at org.mule.tools.deployment.fabric.RequestBuilder.buildTarget (RequestBuilder.java:70)
    at org.mule.tools.deployment.fabric.RequestBuilder.buildDeploymentRequest (RequestBuilder.java:45)
    at org.mule.tools.deployment.fabric.RuntimeFabricArtifactDeployer.deployApplication (RuntimeFabricArtifactDeployer.java:56)
    at org.mule.tools.deployment.fabric.RuntimeFabricApplicationDeployer.deploy (RuntimeFabricApplicationDeployer.java:36)
    at org.mule.tools.deployment.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:50)
    at org.mule.tools.maven.mojo.deploy.DeployMojo.doExecute (DeployMojo.java:37)
    at org.mule.tools.maven.mojo.deploy.AbstractMuleDeployerMojo.execute (AbstractMuleDeployerMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Mule 3 and Mule 4 are not compatible. They require different versions of the Mule Maven Plugin. You are not even using the [last available version of the Mule Maven Plugin 2.x](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-maven-plugin/mule-maven-plugin-release-notes) (at this time) that contains some fixes for Runtime Fabric deployments. Note that you would need to [rename memoryReserved](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-maven-plugin/mule-maven-plugin-2.3.5-release-notes#features-and-functionality) for the newer version. It is strongly recommended to **use the latest available release** of the version compatible with your deployment target.

The error is happening when the plugin tried to authenticate according to the stack trace you shared. Also you mentioned using a connected app to deploy to Mule 4. The Mule Maven Plugin 2.x (for Mule 3.x) [doesn't support connected apps](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Does-Mule3-API-support-Connected-Apps-as-deployment-authentication-method). If you are using a user and password, you need to be sure **it is excluded from multi factor authentication** (MFA) restrictions. Otherwise it is not going to be able to login in a non-interactive way, which is what you need for a Maven deployment. A time out at authentication with the platform suggest this could be the cause of the error.

It would be also recommended to use the last release of Mule 3 (3.9.5) to include all possible bug fixes for known issues, though that is not related to your issue. Mule 3.9.1 was released in 2018.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do use username and password and MFA is also disabled. I have updated maven as you suggest to 2.3.5 and updated the elements only I keep getting the connection time out. unfortunately it is not possible to update the runtime because that is a hard requirement.

Comment: Well, at the least that discards the more obvious reasons. The key line in the log is `    at org.mule.tools.client.authentication.AuthenticationServiceClient.login (AuthenticationServiceClient.java:111)`. That means that the time out is happening at authentication. Other possible causes for the error could be more complex to debug. Are you sure that the target is correct? The comment about 3.9.1 is a suggestion. I don't expect the old release to be related to the issue. However do note that in 2024 3.9 is reaching its EOL.

Comment: Yes, I am sure about the target. I also tried with 3.9.5 to see if it is not a specific 3.9.1 problem, but I also get the same error there.